# Join entre modelos de Django

Tags: python, django, join, orm

tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class A(models.Model):
    folio_real_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
    codigo = models.ForeignKey('personas.B', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True ,     related_name='codigo_folioReal')
    cod_circ = models.ForeignKey('personas.B', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='cod_circ', blank=True, null=True, related_name='codcir_folioReal')
  fk_codigo = models.ForeignKey('personas.B', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_codigo')

class B(models.Model):
    codigo_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    cod_circ = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    id = models.FloatField(unique=True)
```

Es una base que ya estaba generada y que tiene claves primarias compuestas (codigo,cod_circ), por lo que optamos por agregar una nueva columna en el modelo A (fk_codigo) y en B un ID unico. con lo que el join seria a.fk_codigo = b.id

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente query:

`a.objects.select_related('fk_codigo').all().query`

obtengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT "A"."FOLIO_REAL_ID", "A"."CODIGO_ID", "A"."COD_CIRC",
   "A"."FK_CODIGO",
  "B"."CODIGO_ID", "B"."COD_CIRC", "B"."JURIS_ID", "B"."ID" 
  FROM "A" INNER JOIN "B" ON ("A"."FK_CODIGO" = "B"."CODIGO_ID")
```

Es decir que esta haciendo el join por el campo CODIGO_ID.
Como deberia hacer para indicar el campo especifico por el que quiero hacer el join?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

¿Has tratado la siguiente queryset?:

```
a.objects.select_related('cod_circ').all().query
```